# How to create a JSON file getting out data with Java from database?

Tags: java, json

I am working on tablet web app project, but I don't know how to create JSON file getting out info with Java connecting to database. Info is getting through of Store Procedure and data return with `List<Object obj>` or with `ResultSet`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a library called [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples#Example_1-1_-_Encode_a_JSON_object)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Jackson library](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) to convert any Java model object into JSON.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValue(new File("c:\\modelObj.json"), modelObj);
```

or

```
String s = mapper.writeValueAsString(modelObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

A json file is text - so retrieve just as you would any string. If you were using a result set you could use [ResultSet.getString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString%28int%29). Then you probably will want to deserialize it into either a domain object or some form of json object using a json parsing library.

There are lots of different libraries out there for doing this, for instance [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) or [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). I personally prefer gson - probably just because I'm more familiar with it and I find the API quite straight forward.